# ixwebhosting php mail() issues with subject

Tags: php

I encounter a very strange problem with ixwebhosting.

I am able to send email using the php `mail()` function with `$subject = "test";`

But if `$subject = "testing of information send";` then i won't be able to receive any email

But actually "Mail sent!" was displayed in the php page.

```
if (!mail($email, $subject, $body, $from)) { echo "Error Sending Email!"; }

else

{ echo "Mail sent!"; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the email is being classed as spam somewhere down the track? Are you able to get logs from the mailserver indicating whether mail gets sent?